# Imported module for python flask-based webapp asks for input from user

Tags: python, flask, spotipy

I'm using the Spotipy module to code a web app to generate playlists. I'm running into a problem where spotipy prompts the user to enter a URL they're redirected to via terminal. Because the user only sees what flask displays, this is impossible and the app can't progress.

Is there a way to code entering this input? It's going to be the same every time. These are the lines that are the problem. I've commented out some old stuff and am trying some new stuff but I don't think it'll work because I need to be able to create playlists

```
scope = "playlist-modify-public"
redirect_uri = "https://umatt.me/"
#manager = SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope, client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
#spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=manager)
manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=manager)
```

These are the lines that make me think this is the problem

```
Enter the URL you were redirected to: ['Island in The Sun', ' Ms. Jackson', " Day 'N' Nite"]
Enter the URL you were redirected to: ['Island in The Sun', ' Ms. Jackson', " Day 'N' Nite"]
Enter the URL you were redirected to: ['Island in The Sun', ' Ms. Jackson', " Day 'N' Nite"]
Enter the URL you were redirected to: ['Island in The Sun', ' Ms. Jackson', " Day 'N' Nite"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Client Credentials authorization flow, but that's only for server-to-server authentication. If you want to let users login, you should use the [Authorization Code Flow](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/#authorization-code-flow) instead

```py
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

scope = "user-library-read"

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope))

results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
for idx, item in enumerate(results['items']):
    track = item['track']
    print(idx, track['artists'][0]['name'], " – ", track['name'])
```